# T-SQL, round up to nearest .5

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

In SQL Server, I need to be able to round up to the nearest half or whole INT.

0.1 should round to 0.5

0.9 round to 1

2.12 round to 2.5

I have tried different approches using ROUND and CEILING, but can't make it work.
Anyone has a solution for this please?
thanks for your time and help

Comment: The linked post is "rounding to the nearest", this post is "rounding up".  The solution is: Ceiling(Value * 2) / 2

Comment: it works, thanks a lot!!!